# Making a better looking plot legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to plot two (or more) functions, inserting in the plot itself the legend that will clarify me what are those plotted functions. I know this basic standard command lines:

```
 Plot[{Log[x], Log[Sin[x]]}, {x, -1, 23}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{Log[x],  Log[Sin[x]]}, {0.8, 0.8}], 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.004]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.004]}}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 11}]
```

Which works quite good because the output is

[image]

But my problem is that it's really difficult to see the associated colors line in the legend. How can I solve this problem?

If someone knew a solution, or a different (better) code to make those things work better, I would be so thankful!

Comment: This is in V9; the lines in the legend are thicker by default starting in V10.0.

Comment: Yes I have version 9 :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Code:**

```
Plot[
 {Log[x], Log[Sin[x]]}, {x, -1, 23},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{Style[Log[x], Red], Style[Log[Sin[x]], Blue]}, {0.8, 0.8}],
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.004]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.004]}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 11}]
```

**Output:**

[image: Output 1]

**Alternative:**

```
Plot[
 {Log[x], Log[Sin[x]]}, {x, -1, 23},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[{Red, Blue}, {Style["Log[x]", Red, Bold], 
     Style["Log[Sin[x]]", Blue, Bold]}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 10}], {0.8, 0.8}],
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.004]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.004]}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 11}]
```

**Output:**

[image: Output 2]

Comment: Oh this is awesome, it make the legend colored itself! Thank you!!

Comment: Excellent idea, +1

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[{Log[x], Log[Sin[x]]}, {x, -1, 23},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], {0.8, 0.8}],
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.004]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.004]}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 11}]
```

[image]

Or, if you want to frame the legend

```
Plot[{Log[x], Log[Sin[x]]}, {x, -1, 23},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {0.8, 0.8}],
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.004]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.004]}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 11}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome too!! Thank you guys, I bet there are tricks that I still have to know! Today I added a 0.001% more to my M. Knowledge :D